# Changing keyboard backlight causes sound to stutter – why?

Tags: linux, devices

I'm on a Dell Vostro 16 laptop (running elementary OS 7.1 based on Ubuntu 22.04.3, kernel 6.5). The laptop has a backlit keyboard that can be controlled using `/sys/class/leds`. Specifically, to turn off the backlighting, I can do the following:

```bash
sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/dell::kbd_backlight/brightness"
```

However, if I write to the “file” while playing some music at the same time, the music stutters. If it's playing directly from the laptop's speakers, it makes a clicking sound (from missing a few samples, I assume). If it's playing from a bluetooth speaker, it stops for ~200ms.

**Why** is this happening? What is the underlying process that causes this? And is there perhaps a better way to write to `/sys` that would prevent this from happening?

Comment: If I have to venture a guess: uuuuuuuh that sounds like really bad firmware, having to reset, and thus halting PCIe transfers. To verify: have `dmesg -Hwx` run in a second terminal and see what happens when your do that write!

Comment: Unfortunately this is very likely to be a problem either in the kernel driver or in the firmware. There may be a workaround like passing some obscure option somewhere or upgrading/downgrading the kernel/firmware. There's no such thing as a “better way to write to /sys”: that's the lowest level there is between user land and kernel land. There might be a different way to control the brightness, but it's not very likely.

Comment: I used to use a Dell Vostro 3750. My observation was that `sensors` from `lm-sensors`  makes Ubuntu freeze for a split second. I also tried some tool to control the fan (it may have been the `fancontrol` package, I don't remember) and gave up because the OS stuttered every second or two, supposedly when the tool queried the hardware. I don't remember problems with audio, probably because I got disappointed as soon as I observed the mouse cursor taking breaks in its way across the screen, uninstalled the tool and never got to testing audio with it. So probably Dell+Linux is somewhat flawed.

Comment: @MarcusMüller `dmesg -Hwx` doesn't print anything during the write

Comment: There is a [patch in kernel 6.4](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/3ed0b880b71489d59f89b0bc1323ad34a136cca0) that ties the LED driver with sound. I don't know if it could cause this problem, but it would be worth trying a ≤6.3 kernel (with any distribution).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I've just tried kernel 5.15.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.6, and the problem persists.